# Php how to properly connect functions with pagination

Tags: php

Am I doing this right? I do not know how to properly connect functions with pagination. To make everything work, I have to duplicate this variables. When I add variables to the function and to the index, then everything works.

```
$rowperpage = 10; 
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
$page = $page - 1;      
$p = $page * $rowperpage;
```

**Function**

```
function find_all_products_by_cat_id2($cat_id, $options=[]) {
    global $db;

    $visible = $options['visible'] ?? false;

    $rowperpage = 10;
    $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
    $page = $page - 1;
    $p = $page * $rowperpage;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ";
    $sql .= "WHERE cat_id='" . db_escape($db, $cat_id) . "' ";  
    if($visible) {
      $sql .= "AND visible = true ";
    }
    $sql .= "ORDER BY prod_name ASC ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT ".$p.", ".$rowperpage." ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    return $result;
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 

        $rowperpage = 10;
        $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
        $page = $page - 1;
        $p = $page * $rowperpage;

        $category_id = $_GET['id'] ?? 1;

        $products_count = count_products_by_cat_id($category_id, ['visible' => true]);


        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $category_id = $_GET['id'];

        $product_set = find_all_products_by_cat_id2($category_id, ['visible' => true]);

        if(!$product_set) {
            redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
        }

        $product_count = mysqli_num_rows($product_set);

        if($product_count == 0) {
              echo "<h1>No more products</h1>";
              }

 ?>
```

I think I found a solution.

**Update 1**
**Function**

```
  function find_by_sql($sql) {
    global $db;

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    return $result;
  }
```

**index.php**

```
$visible = $options['visible'] ?? false;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ";
$sql .= "WHERE cat_id='" . db_escape($db, $category_id) . "' "; 
if($visible) {
  $sql .= "AND visible = true ";
}
$sql .= "ORDER BY prod_name ASC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT ".$p.", ".$rowperpage." "; 

$product_set = find_by_sql($sql, ['visible' => true]);
```

Comment: "Am I doing this right?" Most importantly, does it work? You say it works when you add variables to the function and the index, does that suffice for your application? Sure, you're looking for something better, but the current code does at least the bare minimum of what is required?

Comment: Its work, I think I found a solution. Check please Update1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a BOOL/BOOLEAN column called `visible`, you might consider using a more recognized syntax like `visible <> 0` or `visible = 0` as advised here: [MySQL: “= true” vs “is true” on BOOLEAN. When is it advisable to use which one? And Which one is vendor independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24801220/2943403) After all, [BOOLEAN columns are really just TINYINT columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

I have to assume that `confirm_result_set($result);` is fetching the rows and preparing them in some manner.  Perhaps you'd like to adjust the variable name to be more intuitive/descriptive.

Some developers, myself included, do not recommend the use of `global` as a means of transferring variables into a function's scope.  IMO, it is cleaner to pass the connection variable as a parameter in the function call (like you do with `$sql`).

I don't know what `db_escape()` is doing, but the surest advice is to urge you to use prepared statements with placeholders.  As a less classy alternative, so long as `$category_id` is an integer, you can cast it as an integer (`(int)$category_id`) before using it in your query. Joomla, for instance, doesn't offer prepared statements yet (available in the next major version) so they use integer/float casting for security on numeric values.  Also, numeric values do not need to be quoted in queries.

`ASC` is not necessary in your query, it is the default sorting direction and can be omitted.

The LIMIT clause string can be written without concatenation: `$sql .= "LIMIT $p, $rowperpage";`

Comment: `function db_escape($connection, $string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  }`